# Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at connect

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I was learning React course on Udemy and in Redux section I met this error ***Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at connect*** . I tried to google it but still didn't find the solution.
Could anyone help me? Thank you a lot.

Counter.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import CounterControl from '../../components/CounterControl/CounterControl';
import CounterOutput from '../../components/CounterOutput/CounterOutput';

class Counter extends Component {
 state = {
     counter: 0
 }

counterChangedHandler = (action, value) => {
    switch (action) {
        case 'inc':
            this.setState((prevState) => { return { counter: prevState.counter + 1 } })
            break;
        case 'dec':
            this.setState((prevState) => { return { counter: prevState.counter - 1 } })
            break;
        case 'add':
            this.setState((prevState) => { return { counter: prevState.counter + value } })
            break;
        case 'sub':
            this.setState((prevState) => { return { counter: prevState.counter - value } })
            break;
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <CounterOutput value={this.props.ctr} />
            <CounterControl label="Increment" clicked={() => this.counterChangedHandler('inc')} />
            <CounterControl label="Decrement" clicked={() => this.counterChangedHandler('dec')} />
            <CounterControl label="Add 5" clicked={() => this.counterChangedHandler('add', 5)} />
            <CounterControl label="Subtract 5" clicked={() => this.counterChangedHandler('sub', 5)} />
        </div>
    );
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
       ctr: state.counter
   }
 };

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Counter);
```

Package.json

```
 {
  "name": "react-complete-guide",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.13",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import reducer from './store/reducer';

const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  counter: 0
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  return state;
};

export default reducer;
```

.............................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been learning the same course and faced the same problem. In the end it was all about the versions of React, Redux and react-redux libs. Because it seems like the course is not up-to-date and uses the 16.0.0 version of React.
A thing that helped me and made my projects built successfully was using the `package.json` file from the `redux--assignment-2-problem` project (it's the project which sources are given in the Section 14 of the course)
So I copied the following `package.json` and pasted it into the project's root folder:

```
{
  "name": "react-complete-guide",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.13",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Then I ran `npm install` with that package config and it all went ok.

Comment: Yeah the same solution to me

Comment: Hi Anton, have you faced the same problem with "redux--assignment-2-problem"? The package.json seems not to work with it

Comment: Hey! Try to remove 'node_modules' folder and 'package-lock.json' file, then run 'npm install' on the project again and see if it works

Comment: Hey @DuyLong did you have luck with building the project? Can you mark the answer as correct (or at least useful) if it solves the problem?

Comment: I did it @Anton

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call `combineReducers` before exporting in `reducer.js`

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
const initialState = {
  counter: 0
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  return state;
};

export default combineReducers({counter: reducer});
```

`counter.js` will also need to be updated:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
       ctr: state.counter.counter
   }
 };
```

Also, from a design standpoint, it makes more sense to store the count in your reducer as an integer rather than an object.

Comment: I made some edits to my original answer.  Are you getting the same error?

Comment: that's interesting.  how far along are you in the course?  I also noticed there are no action creators, which means the redux store isn't being updated.

Comment: I did clone this project from the course and it worked. I found out that the version of react, react-redux, redux kinda older than my version in file package.json. Might be that's the problem.

Comment: That could be it. It might be a good idea to install the updated versions of those modules.